# App-to-User Notifications - Multiple IDS

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

How to send notifications to multiple users in one go, or is it not supported.Do I have to loop through ids to send notifications individually or I can pass an array?

```
$response = $facebook->post('/{user-id}/notifications?access_token='.$app_access_token.'&'.$message.'');
```

OR

```
$response = $facebook->post('/{user-id},{user-id}/notifications?access_token='.$app_access_token.'&'.$message.'');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send them one by one, but you can use Batch Requests to make the call faster. Batch Requests allow 50 API calls at once.

Here´s the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

Comment: Upto how many I can send them one by one. Suppose I have around 3000 users. Its not good practice to hit 3000 hits on server.

Comment: they still count as separate api call, so you would most likely hit api limits. 3000 at once does sound like spam too, to be honest...

Comment: But they are individual user, I want to notify all

Comment: then do it through the day, but i suggest not trying to notifiy 3000 users at once. that´s a different question though, you can´t avoid api limits with batch requests and there is no way to mass-send notifications.